# Is codecademy a good choice to master in web development?

Tags: jquery, html, css, ruby, sass

I have been learning from codecademy quite a while. I want to know if really i am putting my time on quality stuff or not?

Comment: Codeacademy just touches the surface - Search for "the odin project"

Comment: It's an excellent resource for beginners but I don't think anybody mastered 'web development' from there alone. Finish the tracks that you're interested in on CA then source more advanced material. If you're interested in Ruby click [here](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/ruby/info) for info on learning resources.

Answer (score 2):

**PRO:**

- Excellent for absolute beginners (as in you don't even know HTML).
- Great step-by-step instructions and great help when you get stuck.
- Supportive community.
- Wide range of content to learn from; you can find lessons on many
  topics (e.g. HTML, CSS, Ruby, Rails, Python, Javascript ...etc) and
  they keep adding more content.

**CON:**

- Almost too much hand-holding (harkening back to PRO#1 - they're great
  for absolute beginners) doesn't help intermediate students move on to
  learning advanced concepts.
- Disjointed lessons/modules without bringing the student back to the
  "big picture" or "why do I need to know this" can leave a student
  uncertain where to go or how to progress from that point on. This can
  be seen by the number of users asking "Done with Codecademy. What
  now?" type of questions on their forums.
- A mile wide, but an inch deep. Meaning: although they have lots of
  resources and content, they barely cover the surface and they don't
  dive deep enough to get to the next level of programming.

Answer (score 2):

I highly recommend the **[Odin Project](https://www.theodinproject.com/)**. It has a very broad perspective and use many different ways and ressources instead of focusing on one kind teaching.

Codeacademy is a very good resource, but it may be guiding you too much. A big part of programming is actually figuring out what problem you are actually solving, and structuring that project.

The odin project also forces you to work in your own environment, on the console, using git and all this. It is not some walled garden, where everything always plays nicely together.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is code website but depends what you want to learn.
There are other options also.

- Code school
- Pluralsight
- E-books